# Android Java: R.id.variable1..variable2..variable3..etc

Tags: java, android, variables, r.java-file

I'm trying to learn Java for Android and not sure how to even Google this. I was wondering if there's a way to programmably attach a number to the end of R.id.variable or R.drawable.variable etc?

Basically I have several images labeled image1, image2, image3, etc. I want to update the ImageView drawable to be based on another variable. So if that passed variable is "1", it will update the view to "image1". If it's "2" it will update "image2" and so on but I don't know if there's a way to attach "1" to "R.drawable.image" when calling the update.

How is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Would a [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe help:

Your images: image1.png, image2.png, ...., imageN.png

You can find their id :

```
getResources().getIdentifier("IMAGE_NAME", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
```

So:

```
 int idImage1 = getResources().getIdentifier("image1", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
 int idImage2 = getResources().getIdentifier("image2", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
  .....
 int idImageN = getResources().getIdentifier("imageN", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
```

Comment: also worth clarifying the first parameter can be built dynamically ie/  `getResources().getIdentifier("image" + label, "drawable", etc.)` where `label` is a parameter

Comment: Clearly I'm not typing fast enough today :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html).  It can get a bit messy, so for the situation you're describing it's probably better to have your images in an array or list and use the argument as the index to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array! You can of course use whatever data structure you want, you might find that a List (specifically an ArrayList) lets you use some more of the Collections API. Alternatively if you want to refer to your images by name you can use a Map.

```
Image[] myImages = new Image[n];
//populate images e.g. myImages[0] = new Image();

void updateImage(int imageNo) {
    Image i = myImages[imageNp]; //arrays start at 0 not 1
    //do stuff to i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To grab a resource by dynamic name, use [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). That function takes a string and returns the ID of the resource by that name

Here's an example from my code, where I get the resource ID of the string resource with the name "run_*arbitrary-integer*_summary":

```
getResources().getIdentifier(
            String.format("run_%d_summary", mSelectedRun),
            "string", 
            getPackageName()
            );
```

There may be better ways of doing what you're doing, but I'll let people who are more familiar with Android go into that...